# I'm having trouble controlling Android browser scale

Tags: android, html, css

I have a `#scroller` which is layered over the top of a menu and I have a button that `-webkit-transform: translate3d(265px, 0, 0);` to the right.

When it slides to the right, both the scroller and the menu tries to fit on the screen, I don't want this, I want the wrapper to slide off screen.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
body:after {
    content:'mobile';
    display: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* ------ Wrapper ----- */
 #wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 40px;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -o-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
}
.slideout {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(265px, 0, 0);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do to stop Android from trying to fit the whole thing on the screen. I want the `#scroller` to slide off screen.

**HTML**

```
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
      <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<body>
<div class="snap-drawers">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scroller"> 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should also add the HTML markup and ideally a reproduction of the structure on jsfiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by " I want the wrapper to slide off screen." ?

Comment: Have a look at the below answer it follows all the answers to problems related to viewport scaling.And please be more comprehensive next time.

Comment: Yea, I should have mentioned it was only ice sandwhich before. I'll take a look at your answer some more but I'm already using media queries. This works on chrome and newer versions of android but ice cream sandwhich seems to take my transformed div into its scale. Here's a link http://lartmagazine.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
width=device-width, height=device-height,
```

If you want the screen to be able to slide up down add this to you meta viewport:

```
<META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

I hope this works if it doesn't try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0,  user-scalable=0" />
```

If it still doesn't work play around with the initial and maximum scale and it should work.

If you want it to scroll left to right add this :

```
<META NAME="viewport" CONTENT=" height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

For mobiles you should add something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

Use `user-scalable=yes` to allow zoom in or `user-scalable=no` to prevent zoom.

These are not necessary remove them they might be causing the problem:

```
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

Still didn't get them working add css media queries and problem should be solved:

```
(max-width: 640px){
//add code here//
}
(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px){
//add code here//}

(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px){
//add code here//}
}
(min-width: 1025px){
//add code here//}
}
```

Comment: I've tried these before and it wouldn't work, it seems to only be on an android 4.0.4

Comment: I even tried removing it altogether but it still does it.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted those other meta data fields and added one of your suggestions but it still didn't work. As I say this actually works on jelly bean or kitkat it's just ice cream sandwhich' browser for some reason.

Comment: I changed the `#wrapper` `#scroller` to position relative and it worked.

Comment: @UzumakiDev a vote up and a tick would be appreciated

Comment: I gave you a vote up anyway and I gave you a tick for effort but your answer wasn't exactly right. The problem was how ICS handled position absolute.